# Add more functionality to planetaryJS globe

Tags: javascript, planetary.js

I want to add two functionalities in [planetaryJS](http://planetaryjs.com/) globe

1. I wanted to increase Zoom speed for globe created by planetary JS
2. How can I generate multiple pings like the ones being generated [here](https://cybermap.kaspersky.com/). 
   I know it needs a set of longitude and latitude but I am unable to
   do that even for one ping.

Moreover the globe given there is so smooth to rotate than the one provided by planetaryJS

In short I want to implement exactly similar globe like [this](https://cybermap.kaspersky.com/)

Any inputs?

The Kaspersky's globe background is too good. As we rotate globe, the background is moving, how should I implement it?
I have tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4dmq49zm/40/)

```
(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('quakeCanvas');

  // Create our Planetary.js planet and set some initial values;
  // we use several custom plugins, defined at the bottom of the file
  var planet = planetaryjs.planet();
  planet.loadPlugin(autocenter({extraHeight: -120}));
  planet.loadPlugin(autoscale({extraHeight: -120}));
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.earth({
    topojson: { file:   'https://rawgit.com/prashantgpt91/9b0558613b94eb2498325931acf5ea21/raw/0440b7a29db12374257ffdec3d41fda8f7481f3e/world-110m.json' },
    oceans:   { fill:   '#001320' },
    land:     { fill:   '#06304e' },
    borders:  { stroke: '#001320' }
  }));
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.pings());
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.zoom({
    scaleExtent: [10, 10000]
  }));
  planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.drag({
    onDragStart: function() {
      this.plugins.autorotate.pause();
    },
    onDragEnd: function() {
      this.plugins.autorotate.resume();
    }
  }));
  planet.loadPlugin(autorotate(5));
  planet.projection.rotate([100, -10, 0]);
  planet.draw(canvas);


  // Create a color scale for the various earthquake magnitudes; the
  // minimum magnitude in our data set is 2.5.
  var colors = d3.scale.pow()
    .exponent(3)
    .domain([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
      .range(['white', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple']);
  // Also create a scale for mapping magnitudes to ping angle sizes
  var angles = d3.scale.pow()
    .exponent(3)
    .domain([2.5, 10])
    .range([0.5, 15]);
  // And finally, a scale for mapping magnitudes to ping TTLs
  var ttls = d3.scale.pow()
    .exponent(3)
    .domain([2.5, 10])
    .range([2000, 5000]);

  // Create a key to show the magnitudes and their colors
  d3.select('#magnitudes').selectAll('li')
    .data(colors.ticks(9))
  .enter()
    .append('li')
    .style('color', colors)
    .text(function(d) {
      return " ";
    });


  // Load our earthquake data and set up the controls.
  // The data consists of an array of objects in the following format:
  // {
  //   mag:  magnitude_of_quake
  //   lng:  longitude_coordinates
  //   lat:  latitude_coordinates
  //   time: timestamp_of_quake
  // }
  // The data is ordered, with the earliest data being the first in the file.
  d3.json('https://rawgit.com/BinaryMuse/planetary.js/master/site/public/examples/quake/year_quakes_small.json', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      alert("Problem loading the quake data.");
      return;
    }

    var start = parseInt(data[0].time, 10);
    var end = parseInt(data[data.length - 1].time, 10);
    var currentTime = start;
    var lastTick = new Date().getTime();

    var updateDate = function() {
      d3.select('#date').text(moment(currentTime).utc().format("MMM DD YYYY HH:mm UTC"));
    };

    // A scale that maps a percentage of playback to a time
    // from the data; for example, `50` would map to the halfway
    // mark between the first and last items in our data array.
    var percentToDate = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([start, end]);

    // A scale that maps real time passage to data playback time.
    // 12 minutes of real time maps to the entirety of the
    // timespan covered by the data.
    var realToData = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1000 * 60 * 12])
      .range([0, end - start]);

    var paused = false;

    // Pause playback and update the time display
    // while scrubbing using the range input.
    d3.select('#slider')
      .on('change', function(d) {
        currentTime = percentToDate(d3.event.target.value);
        updateDate();
      })
      .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('dragstart', function() {
          paused = true;
        })
        .on('dragend', function() {
          paused = false;
        })
      );


    // The main playback loop; for each tick, we'll see how much
    // time passed in our accelerated playback reel and find all
    // the earthquakes that happened in that timespan, adding
    // them to the globe with a color and angle relative to their magnitudes.
    d3.timer(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      if (paused) {
        lastTick = now;
        return;
      }

      var realDelta = now - lastTick;
      // Avoid switching back to the window only to see thousands of pings;
      // if it's been more than 500 milliseconds since we've updated playback,
      // we'll just set the value to 500 milliseconds.
      if (realDelta > 500) realDelta = 500;
      var dataDelta = realToData(realDelta);

      var toPing = data.filter(function(d) {
        return d.time > currentTime && d.time <= currentTime + dataDelta;
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < toPing.length; i++) {
        var ping = toPing[i];
        planet.plugins.pings.add(ping.lng, ping.lat, {
          // Here we use the `angles` and `colors` scales we built earlier
          // to convert magnitudes to appropriate angles and colors.
          angle: angles(ping.mag),
          color: colors(ping.mag),
          ttl:   ttls(ping.mag)
        });
      }

      currentTime += dataDelta;
      if (currentTime > end) currentTime = start;
      updateDate();
      d3.select('#slider').property('value', percentToDate.invert(currentTime));
      lastTick = now;
    });
  });



  // Plugin to resize the canvas to fill the window and to
  // automatically center the planet when the window size changes
  function autocenter(options) {
    options = options || {};
    var needsCentering = false;
    var globe = null;

    var resize = function() {
      var width  = window.innerWidth + (options.extraWidth || 0);
      var height = window.innerHeight + (options.extraHeight || 0);
      globe.canvas.width = width;
      globe.canvas.height = height;
      globe.projection.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    };

    return function(planet) {
      globe = planet;
      planet.onInit(function() {
        needsCentering = true;
        d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
          needsCentering = true;
        });
      });

      planet.onDraw(function() {
        if (needsCentering) { resize(); needsCentering = false; }
      });
    };
  };

  // Plugin to automatically scale the planet's projection based
  // on the window size when the planet is initialized
  function autoscale(options) {
    options = options || {};
    return function(planet) {
      planet.onInit(function() {
        var width  = window.innerWidth + (options.extraWidth || 0);
        var height = window.innerHeight + (options.extraHeight || 0);
        planet.projection.scale(Math.min(width, height) / 2);
      });
    };
  };

  // Plugin to automatically rotate the globe around its vertical
  // axis a configured number of degrees every second.
  function autorotate(degPerSec) {
    return function(planet) {
      var lastTick = null;
      var paused = false;
      planet.plugins.autorotate = {
        pause:  function() { paused = true;  },
        resume: function() { paused = false; }
      };
      planet.onDraw(function() {
        if (paused || !lastTick) {
          lastTick = new Date();
        } else {
          var now = new Date();
          var delta = now - lastTick;
          var rotation = planet.projection.rotate();
          rotation[0] += degPerSec * delta / 1000;
          if (rotation[0] >= 180) rotation[0] -= 360;
          planet.projection.rotate(rotation);
          lastTick = now;
        }
      });
    };
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'white', 'orange', 'green', 'cyan', 'pink'];
            setInterval(function() {
                var lat = Math.random() * 170 - 85;
                var lng = Math.random() * 360 - 180;
                var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                var angle = Math.random() * 10;
                planet.plugins.pings.add(lng, lat, { color: color, ttl: 2000, angle: angle });
            }, 250);
```

Using above code you can create as many as possible pings with different colors.

Answer (score -1):

To increase zoom speed, change line 17 of your fiddle to

```
planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.zoom({scaleExtent: [500, 10000]}));
```

by changing the 500 here, you can increase the speed of zooming using the scrollwheel / laptop pinch to zoom

There's an example of how to add random pings to your map here on line 40: http://planetaryjs.com/examples/rotating.html

Like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
var lat = Math.random() * 170 - 85;
var lng = Math.random() * 360 - 180;
globe.plugins.pings.add(lng, lat, 'white');
}, 150);
```

It's important to remember that the cybermap by kaspersky is using WebGL, and is not using the planetaryJS library (built on D3.js, which is 2D based). Using WebGL renders the Kaspersky globe much faster, at the expense of a longer development time.

Comment: the edit in line 17 suggested by you will only change the zoom in and zoom out limit

Comment: It will not make glove smoother anymore....
Btw I know kaspersky uses WebGL....but how to achieve the similar smoothness...is what I requested everyone to answer